Remove undecodable storage keys from StorageDoubleMap
I want to remove keys from the storage which cannot be decoded by using unhashed. I know there are undecodable keys because when counting the number of storage keys via MyStorage::<T>::iter_keys().count(), there are error logs.
After digging through the Polkadot SDK, I came up with the following script which is called as remove_undecodable_storage_keys::<TypeOfSecondKey>(MyStorage::<T>::final_prefix()). Unfortunately, this script only cleans up keys on my dev chain but not my production one as everything there can be decoded despite error logs from the MyStorage::<T>::iter_keys().count() check.

Can someone help me spot the issue?
Moreover, do you see any issues using this function for a StorageDoubleMap? The storage (orml_tokens::Accounts) I am trying to clean has two key types: AccountId and MyEnum. For some reason remove_undecodable_storage_keys only iterates over keys of the first enum variant of MyEnum.

fn remove_undecodable_storage_keys<T: parity_scale_codec::Decode + Sized>(
    prefix: [u8; 32],
) -> (u64, u64) {
    let mut previous_key = prefix.clone().to_vec();
    let mut reads: u64 = 1;
    let mut writes: u64 = 0;
    while let Some(next) =
        sp_io::storage::next_key(&previous_key).filter(|n| n.starts_with(&prefix))
    {
        reads.saturating_accrue(1);
        previous_key = next;
        let maybe_value = unhashed::get::<T>(&previous_key);
        match maybe_value {
            Some(_) => continue,
            None => {
                log::debug!(
                    "Removing key which could not be decoded at {:?}",
                    previous_key
                );
                unhashed::kill(&previous_key);
                writes.saturating_accrue(1);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    (reads, writes)
}



if the original issue is coming from decoding keys in the iter_keys of StorageDoubleMap, I would manually iterate all the keys and try to decode them. Also, in your current code, in unhashed::get::<T>(&key) T is the type of value not the key. So, afaiu, that line could be misleading when there is an invalid storage key that has some decodable value to T.
I would do something like this (this is basically modified implementation of IterableStorageDoubleMap::iter_keys()):
fn remove_undecodable_storage_keys<
   K1: Decode + Sized, 
   K2: Decode + Sized, 
   Hasher1: ReversibleStorageHasher, 
   Hasher2: ReversibleStorageHasher
>
(
    prefix: [u8; 32],
){
        // ... inside `while` loop
        reads.saturating_accrue(1);
        previous_key = next;

        if let Some(raw_key_without_prefix) = previous_key.get(32..) { 
                let mut k1_k2_material = Hasher1::reverse(raw_key_without_prefix);
                let k1 = match K1::decode(&mut k1_k2_material) {
                    Some(_) => // do nothing,
                    None => // kill the previous key and continue with iteration
                }
                let mut k2_material = Hasher2::reverse(k1_k2_material);
                let k2 = match K2::decode(&mut k2_material) {
                    // same thing as `k1`
                }
        }


